# Why are my HTML Canvas drawing styles being reset after resize?

Tags: go, canvas, html5-canvas, webassembly

I'm using GoLang and WASM, I want to essentially write a "Hello, World"-esque example by drawing a checkerboard to the HTML canvas.

I set `fillStyle` and `strokeStyle` to `'red'`, and `lineWidth` to `5`. It works until I resize the window and my values get reset.

[image: Correctly drawing to canvas]
[image: No longer drawing to canvas]

I have found through trial and error that if I set my styles after I call `clearRect` it will work as I expect it to. From what I've been reading [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes#Drawing_paths), you should only need to worry if you are using paths. I'm just drawing fill and stroke rectangles so this shouldn't be the issue.

It doesn't make sense, but this works by setting the styles every iteration (note the placement of the `canvasCtx.Set` calls within the loop):

```golang
func main() {
    runForever := make(chan bool)
    window := js.Global()
    canvas := window.Get("document").Call("getElementById", "canvas")
    window.Call("addEventListener", "resize", js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
        width, height := updateCanvasSize(window, canvas)
        fmt.Printf("resize triggered: %f x %f\n", width, height)
        return nil
    }))
    _, _ = updateCanvasSize(window, canvas)

    canvasCtx := canvas.Call("getContext", "2d")

    var renderer js.Func
    renderer = js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
        width, height := getWindowInnerSize(window)
        canvasCtx.Call("clearRect", 0, 0, width, height)
        fmt.Printf("Rendering with: Canvas Size %fx%f  fillStyle=%s strokeStyle%s lineWidth=%f\n",
            width, height,
            canvasCtx.Get("fillStyle").String(),
            canvasCtx.Get("strokeStyle").String(),
            canvasCtx.Get("lineWidth").Float(),
        )
        canvasCtx.Set("fillStyle", "red")
        canvasCtx.Set("strokeStyle", "red")
        canvasCtx.Set("lineWidth", 5)

        squareWidth := width / 8
        squareHeight := height / 8
        offsetWidth := squareWidth * 0.15
        offsetHeight := squareHeight * 0.15
        for i := 0; i < 8; i++ {
            for j := 0; j < 8; j++ {
                if (i+j)%2 == 0 {
                    canvasCtx.Call("strokeRect", float64(i)*squareWidth+offsetWidth, float64(j)*squareHeight+offsetHeight,
                        squareWidth-(2*offsetWidth), squareHeight-(2*offsetHeight))
                } else {
                    canvasCtx.Call("fillRect", float64(i)*squareWidth, float64(j)*squareHeight, squareWidth, squareHeight)
                }
            }
        }
        window.Call("requestAnimationFrame", renderer)
        return nil
    })
    window.Call("requestAnimationFrame", renderer)

    <-runForever
}
```

However setting the canvas values upfront instead of for every iteration does not work:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall/js"
)

func main() {
    runForever := make(chan bool)
    window := js.Global()
    canvas := window.Get("document").Call("getElementById", "canvas")
    window.Call("addEventListener", "resize", js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
        width, height := updateCanvasSize(window, canvas)
        fmt.Printf("resize triggered: %f x %f\n", width, height)
        return nil
    }))
    _, _ = updateCanvasSize(window, canvas)

    canvasCtx := canvas.Call("getContext", "2d")
    canvasCtx.Set("fillStyle", "red")
    canvasCtx.Set("strokeStyle", "red")
    canvasCtx.Set("lineWidth", 5)

    var renderer js.Func
    renderer = js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
        width, height := getWindowInnerSize(window)
        canvasCtx.Call("clearRect", 0, 0, width, height)
        fmt.Printf("Rendering with: Canvas Size %fx%f  fillStyle=%s strokeStyle%s lineWidth=%f\n",
            width, height,
            canvasCtx.Get("fillStyle").String(),
            canvasCtx.Get("strokeStyle").String(),
            canvasCtx.Get("lineWidth").Float(),
        )
        squareWidth := width / 8
        squareHeight := height / 8
        offsetWidth := squareWidth * 0.15
        offsetHeight := squareHeight * 0.15
        for i := 0; i < 8; i++ {
            for j := 0; j < 8; j++ {
                if (i+j)%2 == 0 {
                    canvasCtx.Call("strokeRect", float64(i)*squareWidth+offsetWidth, float64(j)*squareHeight+offsetHeight,
                        squareWidth-(2*offsetWidth), squareHeight-(2*offsetHeight))
                } else {
                    canvasCtx.Call("fillRect", float64(i)*squareWidth, float64(j)*squareHeight, squareWidth, squareHeight)
                }
            }
        }
        window.Call("requestAnimationFrame", renderer)
        return nil
    })
    window.Call("requestAnimationFrame", renderer)

    <-runForever
}

func getWindowInnerSize(window js.Value) (float64, float64) {
    width := window.Get("innerWidth").Float()
    height := window.Get("innerHeight").Float()
    return width, height
}

func updateCanvasSize(window js.Value, canvas js.Value) (float64, float64) {
    width, height := getWindowInnerSize(window)
    canvas.Set("width", width)
    canvas.Set("height", height)
    return width, height
}
```

Explicitly setting these values every time isn't really that big of a deal, but my question is why does this happen? Is this what is supposed to happen (EG: are these side-effects documented somewhere I haven't yet seen) or is there a combination of things *I'm* doing that's causing these unintended side effects (if so, how do I rectify myself so I don't run into more weird side-effects)?

Comment: The 2D context state is reset when the canvas is resized (resolution changed, not the display size as set by CSS rules). This is normal behavior as set out in the specifications.

Comment: The spec re size change  "When the user agent is to reset the rendering context to its default state, it must clear the drawing state stack and everything that drawing state consists of to initial values". Source https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#reset-the-rendering-context-to-its-default-state